# Utilizar muitas interfaces é uma má prática de programação?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, interface, classes-abstratas

Sou estudante em Sistemas de Informação e estou modelando um jogo, um pet virtual que tem suas necessidades e conversa com seu dono, abaixo segue a modelagem das classes e interfaces.

Mostrei para um amigo formado em Ciência da Computação, ele achou que tem muitas interfaces, que não era necessário, eu argumentei que caso no futuro eu poderia dar manutenção e implementar pets da forma que eu quisesse sem muito esforço, podendo criar um pet híbrido entre animal e robo, e atribuindo a ele seus comportamentos através das interfaces, mas enfim ele veio com argumentos de desempenho da aplicação.

Minha dúvida é se minha modelagem (que não está pronta, apenas um esboço) com tantas interfaces é uma má prática de programação? Quando devo utilizar uma interface?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link da imagem](http://postimg.org/image/s2nzv51fv/)

Answer (score 48):

Quando vamos modelar um sistema orientado a objetos, uma das coisas mais importantes que devemos fazer é atribuir a cada tipo (seja interface, classe, estrutura, enumeração ou delegado) um conjunto de conceitos e responsabilidades.

Você está fazendo praticamente uma interface para cada método importante dos seus pets. Praticamente todo animal dorme e come, por exemplo. Você poderia criar uma única interface para agrupar essas funcionalidades. Isso ajuda bastante a manter o trabalho simples porque:

- se você tiver que adicionar mais uma funcionalidade aos animais, basta trabalhar em uma única interface. Não precisa ir a cada classe e fazer ela implementar mais uma interface nova;
- se você tiver que mudar a assinatura de algum método, você não vai ter que rodar por todos os seus animais pra ver quais são afetados, i.e.: fica bem mais fácil controlar quem é afetado por uma mudança de uma interface específica.

Outra coisa, vários sons de animais possuem interfaces próprias na sua implementação. Uma abordagem mais comum é ter um único método (novamente, esse vai na interface geral para animais). Você poderia chamar o método de "talk" ou "speak". Daí, se o animal vai latir, berrar, miar ou chamar o juiz pra reclamar de falta **fica a cargo da implementação do método na classe que for utilizar a herança.**

Finalmente, você pergunta: tá, juntei todos os métodos numa única interface chamada **Pet**. Mas e se eu tiver algum animal que não usa alguma funcionalidade? Por exemplo, uma lesma jamais daria salto mortal pra trás. Nesse caso, você tem várias opções:

- Tratar isso em um método abstrato e dar alguma indicação de que a lesma não pode dar salto mortal pra trás;
- Ser um bastardo e lançar uma [NotImplementedException](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fpt-br%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.notimplementedexception%28v%3Dvs.110%29.aspx&ei=f1q9U7WSEtLgsASy64CYCw&usg=AFQjCNFw-5QHark53LTLYlD-LgQRl2_dOA&bvm=bv.70138588,d.cWc);
- Ser um duplo bastardo e deixar o método vazio.

Em todos os casos, documente bem o que estiver fazendo ;)

Note que não há necessidade de classes específicas para dinossauros e cachorros se você pensar assim. A quantidade de funcionalidades em comum entre ambos é simplesmente grande demais para justificar tal especialização.

Você poderia ter alguma necessidade de especialização, se você fizesse algo do tipo:

- Uma única interface chamada Pet, que pode por exemplo evoluir e se mover;
- Três "sub" interfaces: animal, planta e robô;
- Daí você atribui a cada "sub" interface apenas aquilo que é específico dela. Robô não cresce (eu acho), planta não fala e animal não solta raio da morte.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: +1. Eu incluiria: "Ser um triplo bastardo e mentir, retornando True mas ignorando."

Comment: Concordo com o ponto da implementação do método *speak()*, mas não sei, de certa forma, separar cada ação em uma interface própria até que faz sentido porque facilitaria e muito a criação de interfaces secundárias. Imaginem dois tipos de "animais", *Automaton* e *Android*. Os dois são do tipo *Robot* (interface) que por sua vez é um *Pet*, mas cada um é mais específico que o outro.

Comment: Um Autômato seria qualquer máquina com um ou mais propósito(s) único(s), ao passo de um Androide poderia falar e "dormir". E com métodos específicos em interfaces separadas do jeito que está você pode facilmente atingir esse objetivo sem prejuízo do polimorfismo pois ao s olhos da Aplicação todos serão *Pet*.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto regra geral: especializar demais nas interfaces é um tiro no pé. Basta ver como são usadas interfaces em grandes frameworks como Java ou .NET. Em geral, as interfaces são as mais abrangentes possíveis. Case in point: [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Não estou dizendo que está certo, não tenho domínio tão profundo no assunto pra bater o martelo com tanta força assim. Tampouco estou afirmando que todas essas interfaces são realmente essenciais, que não existe mesmo nenhuma possibilidade de ampliar a abrangência de uma ou outra. Mas que faz um certo sentido, faz.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Até existe motivos para ter interfaces com apenas um método (ou poucos), isto não chega ser um grande problema mas não faz sentido você separar comportamentos que estão relacionados. Eu até entendo o que você está dizendo, há motivos para fazer desta forma (eu explico na minha resposta) mas no momento ele não está fazendo isto. Quando ele mudar o *design* e poderá postar outra pergunta para ajudarmos na nova configuração. Aí talvez algumas interfaces sejam úteis de verdade. Seria legal e fazer isto. Para ver se ele pegou o jeito ou ainda precisa de mais orientações.

Comment: @Renan (shut up and take my +1!) é uma pena que não podemos favoritar respostas, uma das melhores que eu já li aqui na SO-pt.

Comment: @Renan Um objeto não deveria publicar um método que não seja um comportamento dele. Se uma lesma não pode dar salto mortal para trás, por que ela tem um método para acionar este comportamento impossível? Se a lesma publica este método estamos diante de um erro de design.

Comment: Acredito que seja bem nesse ponto que eu tentei chegar, @Caffé. De novo, não estou dizendo que a modelagem do diagrama está correta MAS, tendo cada ação numa interface diferente, é como chegar num shopping, naquelas lojas de doces, e dizer "eu quero esse, esse, aquele e um pouquinho daquele outro" e cada vez vai sair uma coisa diferente, que faz mais ou menos coisas que o anterior sem sobrecarregar ninguém, sem publicar métodos desnecessários e etc.

Comment: No caso da lesma, o melhor seria ter ao menos um interface separando esse comportamento (ou comportamentos), caso contrário você estaria realizando uma quebra de contrato. O [Princípio da substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov) fala sobre isso.

Comment: +1 pelo humor! hauahuahuahua

Answer (score 25):

## Classe Abstrata X Interface

Você começou criando a classe `Pet` com propriedades comuns entre as classes derivadas. Há algum motivo para não continuar fazendo isto para os métodos e eventos? Se passar estes membros comuns para a `Pet` já simplifica muito. O Renan sugeriu juntar tudo em uma interface chamada `Pet`. Mas você já tem esta interface. Uma classe abstrata é ao mesmo tempo uma classe e uma interface. A classe abstrata `Pet` é sua interface.

## Generalize o que puder

Siga a recomendação do Renan e transforme os métodos de emissão de som dos Pets em algo genérico. Lembre-se que a emissão de som é a ação única, o jeito que os sons são emitidos é que vai variar, ou seja, a implementação varia. O que você fez foi exatamente o que está descrito no *link* fornecido pelo Josué Eduardo.

Provavelmente você ainda não entendeu bem a conceituação do que seja a interface. Ela declara ações e não o mecanismo (normalmente, mas não vamos fazer do mecanismo sendo usado de outras forma, nem toda linguagem faz isto), a implementação destas ações. Entenda que interfaces e métodos abstratos de classes abstratas **definem** comportamento, mas **não implementam** este comportamento. Só classes concretas podem implementar os comportamentos. Quando você trata um latido ou um relincho sem a abstração da capacidade dos animais emitirem sons, está deixando de lado uma das vantagens da orientação a objeto que é a abstração real (ter uma abstração de latido para implementar um latido é uma abstração artificial).

Talvez todas estas emissões de sons já estejam contempladas no método `Talk()` e apenas as implementações diferentes sejam necessárias. Neste ponto discordo do Renan que cada tipo de `Pet` não precisa de classes específicas. Precisa para poder fazer as implementações específicas nestas classes. A solução sugerida só funcionaria se todas emissões de sons fossem iguais.

Se o `Talk()` serve para outra coisa, você pode criar outro método genérico para denotar a ação de emissão de sons dos pets, `Speak()` talvez?.

Quando fizer isto, todas as interfaces, individualmente, serão implementadas apenas em uma classe cada. Você consegue dizer porque isto é necessário? Se tiver um bom motivo, ok, se não tiver, acabe com elas. Em geral uma interface só é interessante quando é usada em pelo menos duas classes. Utilização futura não é um bom motivo. Se no futuro precisar, aí sim você cria as interfaces. Não há problemas em criar uma interface e colocar em uma classe já existente desde que o *design* da classe esteja certo. Uma classe existente pode assumir uma interface nova se ela já possui o comportamento desejado. Isto não fere nenhum princípio e não cria problemas.

Digo mais. Se conseguir abstrair os pares de métodos (não force a barra, só faça se for o melhor a fazer), `Eat` e `Recharge`, `Sleep` e `Maintenance`, `Poop` e `OilLeak`, talvez descubra que são a mesma ação com implementações diferentes.

## Implementação futura

Se um dia precisar em um `HybridPet` que implemente alguns métodos (e eventos obviamente) exclusivos do `AnimalPet` **E** também alguns métodos exclusivos do `RoboticPet`, aí você cria a `IAnimalPet` que será usada na classe `AnimalPet` e na `HybridPet` e a `IRoboticPet`que será usada na `RoboticPet` e `HybridPet`. Isto se realmente elas ajudarem alguma coisa. Só precisará de duas interfaces.

## Conclusão

Notou que você precisa de zero interfaces? No seu caso, **você tem muitas interfaces**. Na modelagem atual, uma interface é muito.

Não se esqueça que em classes abstratas, ao contrário das interfaces você pode dar uma implementação padrão nos métodos se elas coincidirem para alguns tipos de pets.

Não se preocupe com o futuro neste caso. Se você tiver dificuldade em criar uma interface consistente no futuro é porque seu modelo estava errado, não porque você deixou de criar a interface antes.

Eu acho seu caso bem simples e não precisa fazer a gambiarra de tornar uma especialização uma exceção (e provavelmente gerar uma exceção em *runtime* neste caso) como sugerido pelo Renan.

Se melhorar a modelagem e ainda tiver dúvidas poste nova pergunta para continuarmos ajudando com o novo problema.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

Neste caso é má prática porque você está escrevendo código inútil. Crie apenas as interfaces que são necessárias **agora**.

Deixe para criar no futuro as interfaces que serão necessárias no futuro. Isso não vai aumentar em nada o teu esforço - a IDE cria interfaces automaticamente para você e já altera o código que referencia a implementação para que passe a referenciar a interface, e mesmo que a IDE não fizesse isso o esforço não seria mais que um "pesquisar e substituir".

Ao contrário do que seu amigo disse, o desempenho da aplicação não vai mudar em absolutamente nada, mas seu código ficará mais simples, o que, dentre outros benefícios, diminui o desperdício.

Comment: É o famoso princípio [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Answer (score 8):

Cara se você tem uma interface para uma implementação, não vejo utilidade alguma ter a interface. Muita gente usa como argumento: "se você precisar um dia estender a classe é mais fácil", mas esse dia nunca chega.

Se você tem mais de uma implementação para a interface, ok... mas porque o uso da interface ? do ponto de vista prático, ela é necessária ?... não inche seu código só pra ficar "arquiteturalmente bonito" quanto mais simples melhor.

Te aconselho a dar uma olhada nesse blog do [Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/service_s_new_serviceimpl_why), e também procure por alguns workshops dele. Apesar de ser voltado a Java, ele tem alguns conceitos muito interessantes sobre OO, que se aplicam a qualquer linguagem.

Comment: *Aham...* E o OCP que se exploda, né? Do jeito que essa modelagem se encontra hoje, num futuro, seja ele próximo ou não, ele pode facilmente criar um novo animal completamente novo, com características únicas, muito provavelmente (vai depender da implementação) sem sequer tocar no código que faz o animal comer, dormir, falar...

Comment: @BrunoAugusto OCP e interfaces não se relacionam. Mesmo que você não tenha uma interface **hoje** não significa que a classe não possa ser estendida. Você pode adicionar uma interface quando quiser sem causar nenhum problema (se causar, o design estava errado, não era a falta da interface). Claro que para não modificar a classe, a interface nova em classe existente deverá ser em cima de algo já implementado (ou definido em caso de classe abstrata). Você estaria apenas dizendo que algo existente agora passa ser parte de uma interface. Criar antes viola o YIAGNI ou mesmo o KISS, que é pior.

Comment: Como deu pra notar nos outros comentários eu vejo por outro ângulo, talvez errado, mas OCP é para os fortes :p. Penso que se existe uma interface própria através do qual a Aplicação executa, sei lá, uma ação de comer, qualquer recurso que possa de fato comer pode ser criado a qualquer tempo sem necessidade de modificar a Aplicação consumidora. Se você tem outras tantas interfaces no mesmo sentido você pode fechar a Aplicação consumidora para modificações pois através do polimorfismo proporcionado pela interface *Pet* qualquer classe seria aceita e teria sua ação de comer realizada com sucesso.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Mas não precisa mudar o "consumidor" (como você diz), você não vai mudá-lo. Precisa incluir a interface, não a implementação. OCP tem a ver com **implementação**. Tanto que uma das mais conhecidas técnicas de *refactoring* é o *Extract Interface* que é feito à partir da implementação já existente. Adicionar uma interface nova a uma classe existente não muda a implementação da classe, muito menos quebra qualquer contrato de compilação ou *runtime*.

Comment: Eu sempre tive uma grande dificuldade em entender alguns dos paradigmas assim, só na base teórica. E o fato de material de qualidade sobre assunto relacionado com a linguagem de que eu gosto não existir ou ser bem escasso não contribui em nada. O que me dá mais raiva é que você tá explicando, tá explicando e eu não consigo visualizar do mesmo jeito que você(s). Acho que eu preciso de um café. >.<

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ,acredito que o bigown e eu compartilhamos de um mesmo ponto de vista: o prático. Sempre que for pensar em arquitetura / estrutura se pergunte o "porque preciso?","pode ser mais simples ?". Outra coisa que o bigown sitou que eu aprovo 100%. é a questão de classe abstrata no lugar das interfaces, para ter um comportamento padrão.

Comment: Pois é, eu sei bem disso. Mas como eu não programo profissionalmente posso "me dar ao luxo" de considerar esse tipo de cenário como viável.

Answer (score 5):

Respondendo a sua pergunta: Não é má prática. Mais você deve seguir alguns princípios na hora de fazer a modelagem, segundo o princípio [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) você não precisa criar interfaces para todas as suas classes pelo simples fato de que você nunca irá utilizar, mas se você está com dúvidas na hora de modelar certa classe sugiro a criação de uma interface, principalmente se você está desenvolvendo um pacote ou utilizando e quer um baixo nível de acoplamento.

Answer (score 5):

Apenas utilize Interfaces se utilizar `Design by contract` ([DbC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_contract)).

Se não usa DbC, mantenha seu código enxuto sem utilizar interfaces.

Isto é "o melhor" a partir dos valores do Lean Software Development pois elimina desperdícios. Obviamente, a partir de outros valores, este "melhor" pode ser diferente.

Eu acredito que o uso de uma interface serve para garantir que um objeto possui propriedades requeridas no momento em que será utilizado, forçando a execução disto com Tipagem. Se não preciso desta garantia, logo a criação e implementação de interface é um esforço em vão. Se espero um objeto Logger, espero que ele tenha um método que me permite registrar uma string, portanto digo que o objeto Logger que receberei deverá ao menos possuir um método `foo(string)` e assim terei certeza que a aplicação funcionará. Mas isto é válido apenas se as possibilidades de injeção de Logger forem mais que uma, como por exemplo, quando você desenvolve uma biblioteca que grava logs, mas espera que o Logger seja injetado pela aplicação que usará sua biblioteca.

Comment: Por que isto é o melhor a se fazer?

Comment: @bigown, isto é "o melhor" a partir dos valores do Lean Software Development pois elimina desperdícios. Obviamente, a partir de outros valores, este "melhor" pode ser diferente.

Comment: ok, mas qual a vantagem? Que desperdício? Se eu preciso tomar banho não estou desperdiçando água? Se deixo o chuveiro ligado e vou fazer outra coisa é que estou. Porque a interface é não é desperdício c/ DbC mas é se não usá-lo? Acredito que tenha alguma sustentação no que você disse mas como é algo que parece ir contra tudo o que é estudado sobre o assunto, não podemos simplesmente confiar na sua afirmação. Dê alguma informação adicional para aprendermos algo novo.

Comment: Entendo. Editarei minha resposta e você me dá sua opinião.

Comment: Melhorou bastante mas ainda não entendi a relação com o DbC. Tudo isto que você explicou é necessário independente do DbC ser usado. A não ser que você tenha uma definição de DbC diferente da que eu tenho. O compilador recusar compilar algo que não seja do tipo adequado (não tem a interface requerida) para você é DbC?

Comment: Vejo que o fato de não compilar é apenas um detalhe técnico, mas sim a arquitetura planejada para a orientação ao contrato e Dependence Injection é o que realmente importa isto se aplica também para linguagens onde não compilamos uma build.

Answer (score -1):

Usar interface pra tudo é uma péssima prática pois dificulta muito saber onde realmente a interface está sendo utilizada de forma útil (se é que alguma está sendo), isto é, voltada para a finalidade que ela foi criada.