# O que é uma interface?

Tags: terminologia, interface

*Background* (**TL;DR**):
Estou trabalhando num projeto ASP.NET *legacy*, estava testando algumas funcionalidades dele quando recebi um erro no console do browser: 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
Prontamente fui debugar o código para descobrir o que levava ao erro quando me deparei com um método que recebia 2 parâmetros, porém quando eu acessava ele apertando F12 no Visual Studio, me levava a uma pagina com varias definições de listas com o nome do objeto.

Quando perguntei ao meu supervisor, ele me deu uma definição vaga, falando que aquele "método" era na verdade uma interface, ao pesquisar notei que em muitos artigos há a frase:

> Interface é o nome dado para o modo como ocorre a “comunicação” entre duas partes distintas e que não podem se conectar diretamente.

No caso a interface em questão era uma *query*, porém não vejo benefícios de adotar esse tipo de implementação, já que dificulta a leitura do programa e consequentemente deixa mais difícil de resolver os problemas do código.

**Pergunta:**

- Qual o conceito de interface em programação?
- Quais os benefícios ao usar uma interface na implementação?
- Como vejo o conteúdo de uma interface?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2913/em-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos-por-que-interfaces-s%C3%A3o-%C3%BAteis

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23900/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101 será que uma dessas ou a combinação delas não dá uma duplicata? Eu acho que dá pra deixar ela mais específica e talvez menos ampla, mas do jeito que está, mais geral, já que já foi respondido.

Comment: @bigown sim, a combinação dessas satisfaz o que estava procurando, muito obrigado

Comment: @RovannLinhalis realmente o primeiro tópico e o segundo são basicamente a pergunta no link, muito obrigado