# Diferença entre herança de tipo e herança de implementação

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, interface

Meu professor passou uma apostila sobre Estrutura de dados orientada a objetos com Java e na apostila tem um trecho (sem aprofundamento) que diz o seguinte:

> "Interface   promove   herança   de   tipo   e   não   herança   de
>   implementação; "

Qual a diferença entre esses dois tipos de herança?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata):[Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2913/em-orientação-a-objetos-por-que-interfaces-são-úteis)

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata): [O que é uma interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216019/o-que-é-uma-interface?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa apostila está defasada, hoje [interface pode ter implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101).

Herança de tipo é assumir os contratos que um tipo oferece, ou seja, ter garantidamente todos os [métodos com suas assinaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) de um tipo em um novo tipo. O tipo herda o que já foi declarado em outro tipo.

Herança de implementação recebe o algoritmo, o código que executa nos métodos, e pode até mesmo receber detalhes de implementação como os campos do tipo. [Interface nunca tem estado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101).

A herança de implementação tem a ver com orientação a objetos. A herança de tipo tem a ver com a tipagem estática, ou pelo menos a tipagem segura.

[Isso pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263289/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).