# Erro em Java ao criar classe privada

Tags: java

Toda vez que tento criar uma classe privada em java não estou conseguindo. Segue o código completo abaixo.

```
package execucaodeprogramas;

import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CheckBoxTest extends JFrame{
    private JTextField fiel;
    private JCheckBox bold, italic;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CheckBoxTest application = new CheckBoxTest();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener{

    }
}
```

Estou usando o netBeans e toda vez da erro nesta parte. O erro fica no nome da classe.

```
private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener{  
    }
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro não está relacionado a assinatura do método, e sim pelo fato de você estar implementando a interface [`ItemListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html). Quando você implementa uma interface, você é obrigado a implementar todos os métodos que esta interface possui, no caso da interface citada, possui apenas o método `itemStateChanged`, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener{

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Para entender melhor o funcionamento de interfaces, sugiro que visite todas as perguntas listadas [nesta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216019/28595).